# Tool for Bulk DNS Lookup with Domain or IP Information

Tags: dns-lookup

Suggest me a tool for DNS Lookup and it should have following features.

1. Bulk DNS Lookup (Input .txt to Output .txt)
2. Should have Forward and Reverse Lookup
3. Should find Domain or IP information. Ex. Owner of domain or IP.

When i googled, I got [NS-Batch](http://www.jimprice.com/jim-soft.shtml), But it doesn't have option for get Information.

If my question didn't match for [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com), migrate it to [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) or [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Sorry, but [shopping questions like this are off-topic on ALL stack exchange sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Google might be able to help you further, or you can write a script (shell, powershell, whatever's appropriate for your OS) that takes an input list and Does The Right Thing pretty easily...

Comment: `for i in site1 site2 ... siten; do host $i dns_server; done` where dns_server could be 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4. 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the tool [IPNetInfo](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ipnetinfo.html)